# GridView, adding header row in code Part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is a continuation of this posting, but adding full code:
[ASP.NET - GridView, adding header row in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119004/asp-net-gridview-adding-header-row-in-code)

I am trying to add the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags to my `gridview` control.

Nothing I have tried is working.  I continue to get the error:

```
The table must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer.
```

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
LoadGridView();
}

protected DataView GetDataSource()
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = GetDataset();

DataTable dtRequests = ds.Tables["Admin"];
DataView dv = new DataView(dtRequests);

if (ViewState["sortexpression"] != null)
{
dv.Sort = ViewState["sortexpression"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["sortdirection"].ToString();
}
else
{
dv.Sort = "dtRequestDate DESC";
}

ds.Dispose();
return dv;
}

private void LoadGridView()
{   
gvShipments.DataSource = GetDataSource();
gvShipments.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (gvShipments.Rows.Count > 0)
{
gvShipments.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
gvShipments.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
}

private DataSet GetDataset()
{
Tools oTools = new Tools();

SqlConnection conn = new     SqlConnection(csShipping);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[cGetOpenShipments]";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Connection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds, "Admin");

cmd.Connection.Close();

da.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();

return ds;
}   

protected void gvShipments_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
ViewState["sortexpression"] = e.SortExpression;

if (ViewState["sortdirection"] == null)
{
ViewState["sortdirection"] = "asc";
}
else
{
if (ViewState["sortdirection"].ToString() == "asc")
{
ViewState["sortdirection"] = "desc";
}
else
{
ViewState["sortdirection"] = "asc";
}
}
LoadGridView();
}

protected void gvShipments_PageIndexChanging(object sender,    GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
gvShipments.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
LoadGridView();
}
}
}
```

Comment: ok now what exactly you want to do ? you want to set your gridview header column text ?? or anything else ? how you want your gridview look like ??

Comment: I need to make sure that when the gridview renders, it adds the <theader> and <tbody> tags.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have this setting in your Gridview, and it is trying to generate a Pager above the thead:

```
<PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
```

If you want to have a pager in the header and footer, you also have to set those Pagers to have be `TableRowSection.TableHeader` and `TableRowSection.TableFooter` respectively.

So use the following code:

```
gvShipments.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
gvShipments.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
if (gvShipments.TopPagerRow != null)
{
     gvShipments.TopPagerRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
if (gvShipments.BottomPagerRow != null)
{
     gvShipments.BottomPagerRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to BRYAN!  Awesome job sir.